# CF & ActiveMQ integration?

Tags: coldfusion, activemq-classic

Anyone tried integrating CF with ActiveMQ?  How was the experience?  Worth spending time to build a new solution on it?  I would like to learn more on how to use it, any resource you can point me to?

**update:** Can ActiveMQ run under JRun together with ColdFusion? We're using the Standard Edition.

Thanks

Comment: I wrote both the JMS gateway for CFMX7 and the ActiveMQ gateway for CF8 (which is actually a completely generic JMS event gateway - with much-expanded functionality). Feel free to contact me directly if you need more information. I used both extensively while I was working at Macromedia!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes we have used ActiveMQ, in fact we have a project going on at the moment to consume data via a ColdFusion event gateway using ActiveMQ.

**Note: we are running on ColdFusion 9.0.1 and we are only consuming messages.**

First place to start looking is in your own ColdFusion installation which comes with an ActiveMQ example! Look in `{cf_root}\gateway\docs`.

So to get setup you need to:

Add the ActiveMQ jar (`activemq-all-5.5.0.jar`) file (available [here](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-550-release.html)) to the CF `{cf_root}/lib` directory

Move the `examples.jar` file in `{cf_root}\gateway\lib` to `{cf_root}/lib`

Check out the `{cf_install}/gateway/docs/ActiveMQ_DeveloperGuide.pdf` which will tell you how to create a configuration file. It should look something like this `heartbeat.cfg` example:

```
debug=yes
topic=yes
# the line below needs to be changed
providerURL=tcp://xxx.yyy.com:61616
initialContextFactory=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
connectionFactory=ConnectionFactory

# ActiveMQ requires fake JNDI entries to lookup topic names
contextProperties=topic.heartbeatTopic
topic.heartbeatTopic=com.xxx.yyy.public.heart_beat
destinationName=heartbeatTopic
```

Next, set up the event gateway:

- GatewayID: MyTestActiveMQGateway
- Gateway Type: ActiveMQ (this is an option on CF9)
- CFC Path: `c:\foo\MyCFC.cfc` (this is the CFC that will handle data incoming)
- Configuration File: `c:\foo\heartbeat.cfg`

Your CFC should look like so:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction name="onIncomingMessage" access="public" output="true">
        <cfargument name="data" type="struct" />

        <cflog log="application" text="message arrived!" />


    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Start your event gateway, and lo and behold you should get messages coming in, or some sort of error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am new to all this, so you already have an existing system using ActiveMQ? or you picked ActiveMQ because it fits well with what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can ActiveMQ run under JRun together with ColdFusion?  We're using the Standard Edition...

Comment: We were told to use a REST API to get data from a third party (which we have to poll) or they told us we could use an ActiveMQ feed to get updates 'pushed' to us. Polling can be very inefficient so we decided to go with a push feed. So the 3rd party suggested the technology and we could do it with CF, so no problem. Using ActiveMQ just means using an event gateway, so if there are no restrictions to using event gateways with CF Standard Edition then you'll be fine.

Comment: Is the above solution also applicable for CF8 ?